# Since there is no Clarity filter in Photoshop, how can I simulate that effect?

Tags: photoshop, filters

Why is there no **Clarity** filter in Photoshop? If one opens a camera RAW file it's possible to manipulate image clarity but when the image's inside Photoshop there's nothing like mid-tone contrast manipulation filter like Clarity.

**Is it possible to simulate it somehow** using a combination of other filters and likely masks etc?

Comment: It is available as a filter in a Photoshop CC via the use of the ACR facilities as a filter direct from within Photoshop.

Comment: JoanneC: I've stated above yes that Clarity filter is available on ACR but **not within Photoshop itself** when you open whatever other file than camera RAW. Or I'm just misunderstanding your comment and don't see the actual filter being built in...

Comment: You're misunderstanding, see answer below.

Comment: The question is how can we imitate the Clarity within Photoshop (Assuming no access to ACE as a filter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Photoshop CC, you can essentially use ACR with *any* image, by choosing **Filter Menu > Camera Raw Filter**.

Comment: Then Clarity is just what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made the [Very High Radius Unsharp Mask](http://www.russellcottrell.com/photo/VHRUnsharpMask.asp) plugin to extend the clarity filter as the latter tends to not work well with very large images.

—Russell